# Particle motion in 2D for calculus II help?

Tags: calculus

**Q: A particle moves on the curve $ y = ln(x) $ so that the x-component has velocity $x'(t)= t+1$ for t=0, the particle is at the point (1,0). At time t=1, the particle is at the point?**

My work thus far: I recognize that x(t) -> v(t)->a(t) by differentials in a linear path. I believe this extend to all further dimensions as well. Since we are provided with dx/dt, and I can easily integrate the x-component velocity to arrive at $$ x(t)=t^2/2+t+C $$. C= -3/2 when t=0, so $$ x(t)=t^2/2+t-3/2.$$

Here is where I am stuck: I know that since $y = ln(x) $ increases in y-component as the x-component goes to the right just by knowledge of the graph shape, and I believe the answer I want should be the magnitude of both components x & y. But I am at a loss on how to find the y-component vector since it should be a function of time. How do I finish this conceptually (I don't even really care about the answer want to know what I'm missing)?

Comment: wait is the y-component position just ln(x)?

Comment: Yes, but see my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had a "D'oh!" moment (a la Homer Simpson). As you rightly pointed out, you can greatly simplify the working by just taking the log of the x component. I've edited my answer. Please note this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you solved for $C$ wrongly. $x = 1$ when $t = 0$, so $C = 1$, giving $\displaystyle x(t) = \frac 12 t^2 + t + 1$.

To get $y(t)$, proceed as follows:

By chain rule, $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx} \cdot \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac 1x \cdot (t+1)$.

Putting the expression for $x(t)$ we've derived into that you get:

$\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{t+1}{\frac 12 t^2 + t + 1}$

Solve that by separating variables,

$\displaystyle \int dy = \int \frac{t+1}{\frac 12 t^2 + t + 1}dt$

Note that on the RHS, the numerator is the exact derivative of the denominator, so:

$\displaystyle y(t) = \ln|\frac 12 t^2 + t + 1| + D$

where $D$ is another constant to solve for. When $t = 0, y = 0$ so $D = 0$.

So you get $\displaystyle y(t) = \ln|\frac 12 t^2 + t + 1|$

When $t = 1$, therefore $\displaystyle y = \ln\frac 52$ and $\displaystyle x = \frac 52$ so at $t=1$, the particle is at $\displaystyle (\frac 52, \ln\frac 52)$.

EDIT: As you correctly observed, you can just write $y(t) = \ln x(t)$ and immediately get the answer that way. So we can really shorten the working. I'm leaving the full working here as an example of how one can overthink a simple problem!

Comment: I appreciate it, and it gave me some insight into solving more 'challenging' math problems along my education.

Comment: any idea why this type of question got down-voted? I tried to show I gave a good faith effort and I didn't even beg for a rigorous solution like you gave me...Just want to know in the future in case I come back

Comment: @Chris Honestly I'm not sure what happened in your case (needless to say, it wasn't me lol). Did you edit the question after initially posting it to include details of your working? If so, that could be the reason-the downvote could've happened when the question was initially posted with fewer details - lots of users have a major issue when the asker doesn't show any effort/working. But I always think a comment is better than a downvote or close-vote (or at least in tandem with one or both of those) so that the asker can understand what's going on. Sadly, not everyone shares this perspective.

Comment: @Chris I've added an upvote to offset.

Comment: no worries and I'm not obsessed about points or w/e just for future reference. I did initially tag this as a physics problem along with calculus, and I made one readability edit quickly after I posted regarding formatting, but that's it. I'm smart enough to know not to enter a stack exchange site without showing due diligence.